# Touched events created in a for loop

Tags: java, android, playing-cards, event-handling

All I want is a simple "yes/possible" or "no/and that's bad coding".

I have a card game I'm making and looking through your discard pile is a big part of it, so it's going to be constantly growing.

Can I make a `for` loop to create new touch event so I don't have to make an `if` statement for every new card in the discard pile (because we programmers are lazy)?

```
int len = touchEvents.size();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
    if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

    int x = 5;
    for (int j = 0; j < board.turn.hand.deck.length; j++) {
        if (event.x > x && event.x < x + 60 && event.y > 90 && event.y < 170) {
            board.turn.discard.discard(board.turn.hand.deck[i]);
            board.turn.hand.deck[i] = null;
            discardAmount--;
        }
        x = x + 65;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm afraid this question does not match what this site is about. Code Review is about improving the cleanliness of existing, working code. This question seems to be about "Will this work?" which is not a question for Code Review. The best way to find out is to try it. Once you have code that you are certain does what you want, we would love to help you do the same thing in a cleaner way!

Comment: Overall I find your question very unclear, and part of it is because of a lack of context. In which method is this code? From where do you get your list of `TouchEvent`s ? Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

Your code indicates that you have a serious problem with your object oriented design. Objects are supposed to be 'opaque', and you should not be able to see the structure of the data in your object. Instead, you have this code, which is somehow able to access:

- `board.turn.hand.deck` which appears to be an array, inside a Hand class?
- `board.turn.discard` which in turn has a `discard()` method?

Your code is inverted. The code I am seeing here would appear to belong in the class that you have referenced as `board.turn`, whatever that class is, is likely where this code belongs.

You should mark all those variables/fields as private, and discover what you need to do in order to put the code where it belongs. The following should all be private fields:

- board
- board.turn
- board.turn.hand
- board.turn.hand.deck
- board.turn.discard

In fact, you should not have any not-private fields (unless they are public static final).